# Parse html string and delete some elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a html string and I need to remove all between first occurrence of `<div class="c` and first close tag `>` and last closing tag "`</div>`". The first, should be this because it class is dynamically generated.

For example: `<div class="c2029" style="font-size:45px"><p class="auto">Testing 123...</p></div>` should be transformed to `<p class="auto">Testing 123...</p>`

I tried this, but it's removing all string:

```
var testString = '<div class="c2029" style="font-size:45px"><p class="auto">Testing 123...</p></div>'
var result = testString.replace(/\<div\_c.*\>/, '');
```

**The content into div that should be removed is dynamically generated, it is an example.**

More examples of dynamic string generated:

```
var testString = '<div class="c03"><div style="text-align: center">Testing 123...</div></div>';
var testString = '<div class="c435">Hello</div>';
var testString = '<div class="c1980"><a href="stackoverflow.com">TEST</a></div>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Stack Overflow answers, I found this solution that resolve my problem:

```js
var testString = '<div class="c2029" style="font-size:45px"><p class="auto">Testing 123...</p></div>'
var result = testString.replace(/<div class="c.*?>(.*?)<\/div>/, '$1');
document.write(result);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: ***The above approach works fine but should not be used to manipulate elements, there are lot better approaches than this one.***

Answer (score 2):

Regex is wrong tool for this. You can just `$.parseHTML()` and then `find()` using `[name^=”value”]` selector and use it:

```js
var all = ['<div><div class="c2029" style="font-size:45px"><p class="auto">Testing 123...</p></div></div>', '<div><div class="c435">Hello</div></div>', '<div><div class="c1980"><a href="stackoverflow.com">TEST</a></div></div>'];

$.each(all, function(k,s) { f(s); });

function f(s) {
    var nodes = $($.parseHTML(s)); // parse string to jquery object
    var $p = nodes.find('div[class^="c"]'); // select all classes that starts with c

    var inner = $p.prop('innerHTML'); // inner html of $p
    console.log("Inner: " + inner);
 
    $p.html(''); // select children of $p and remove
    var outer = $p.prop('outerHTML'); // outer html of $p
    console.log("Outer: " + outer);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The tag <p> is an exemple, the content in div that should be removed is dynamic

Comment: @JulyanoFelipe Does not matter, you can find it using right tools. But regex is a big no!

Comment: @JulyanoFelipe Can you post few more examples of the *dynamic content*?

Comment: Is it work with special characteres? I'm getting undefined with characteres like "á" and "ã" into div's content

Comment: @JulyanoFelipe Those have different unicode codepoints. and you will need to use the exact same character instead of `a` to make it work

Answer (score 2):

No need to use regular expressions, you can achieve this with jQuery's [$.fn.unwrap](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/):

```js
$('[class^="c"]').children().unwrap()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="c2029" style="font-size:45px">
  <p class="auto">Testing 123...</p>
</div>
```

To make it more bullet proof and target only element with class staring with "c" and with numbers after you could add additional filtering step:

```
$('[class^="c"]').filter(function () {
  return this.className.match(/\bc\d+\b/)
}).children().unwrap()
```

This way it will not affect classes like `cello` (starts with "c").

Comment: But as I said, the class is generated dynamically

Comment: Do you know that there is `. auto` inside or anything that you know for sure?

Comment: Not, that's why I'm trying to use regex, because all into the div that must be removed is dynamic

Comment: Still possible without hardcode regexp. Check updated approach.

Comment: @dfsq Sorry, I couldn't reply to your comment but the thing is I am parsing html string and you are dumping the html in dom, there is a big difference :)

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I know. I didn't understand from OP wording what he really needs actually.